# Xamarin.Forms: Navigation away from Master Page loses arrow

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having this little drawer menu in my master detail page. I have a list with clickable options there and some navigate you to another screen:

```cs
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Screen_Profile("", true));
```

But this results in the loss of the navigation arrow to go back. If you click back on android, the app just closes afterwards.

How can I navigate away from the master detail page and still have the arrow to just come back to the main page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only want to update the `Detail` page, your the entire `MainPage`

```
var mdPage = (MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage;
mdPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Screen_Profile("", true));
```

this will leave the `Master` portion of the page with it's menu active as you Navigate